# Copying string array into another string array - C

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct that has an array of strings (char **args). I need to be able to copy an array of strings (char *input[32]) into that element of the struct. For example:

```
Thing s;
s.args = input; //assuming input already has some strings in it
```

When I try to do that, the next time s.args = input is called, it completely overwrites the old input. How can I achieve this functionality in the appropriate manner?

EDIT

This is what the struct looks like.

```
typedef struct{
char **args;
} Thing;
```

Then in my function, I have declared:

```
char *args[512];
.....
args[count] = string //string is a char *
```

Then finally, I want to do:

```
s.args = input.
```

Comment: You mean that you want to extend the current array of strings with more strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not copying it.  You are actually just setting the pointer.  Effectively you have this:

```
char **args;
char *other[32];
args = other;
```

You need to actually copy the array - for that you need to allocate memory for it:

```
s.args = malloc( 32 * sizeof(char*) );

for( i = 0; i < 32; i++ ) s.args[i] = input[i];
```

That is a shallow copy - it will copy your string pointers but not duplicate them.  If you change the contents of a string in `input`, that change will be reflected in `s.args`.  To copy the strings, you must do this:

```
for( i = 0; i < 32; i++ ) s.args[i] = strdup(input[i]);
```

Since you have allocated memory, then before you overwrite `s.args` again (and also when your program is finished) you need to free what you allocated.  This includes the strings (if you called `strdup`);

```
if( s.args != NULL ) {
    // Only do the loop if you did a deep copy.
    for( i = 0; i < 32; i++ ) free(s.args[i]);

    // Free the array itself
    free(s.args);
}
```

Comment: Oops, I misread one important fact in the question.  Have edited to correct my answer.

Comment: So if I use strdup, the order of what I have to do is like this?: 1) allocat memory 2) free the the allocated space 3) copy with s.args[i] = strdup(input[i]) ?

Comment: Yes.  Allocate the array first, then `strdup` each string into it.  When you're done, `free` the strings first, then the array.

Comment: Oh, you edited your comment while I was answering the old one.  No.  You only free pointers that you have allocated (*eg* `malloc` or `strdup`).  After you allocate the array, its contents will be undefined.  You don't go and free those values until after you have initialised them.

Comment: Never mind, complete error on my part. Your code is correct. Thank you so much!

Comment: please don't cast the return of `malloc`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Thanks for that @JensGustedt -- I always work with a C++ compiler, and am required to cast when I use `malloc`.  I've gotten into the habit of doing so.  I will edit the cast out of my answer.